# Filter data between ranges

Tags: javascript, angular

I want to filter data based on drop down of the range of price
example first drop down should be:-
$15 so that filter data should be lower or equal to $15 and drop down should show $15. If second is $15-$50 then how I show data in drop down $15-$50 and filter accordingly. What I tried is [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-g2acj4?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) but couldn't get what I want. Here is what I tried and still trying to get the desired result, Hope someone could help me.

.html
 file is

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm">
 <select name="Price" formControlName="filterProduct">
   <option *ngFor="let k of PriceFilter  | groupBy: 'Value' | keyvalue">
  <div>
   <ng-container *ngFor= "let i of k['value']">
    <span>{{i['DisplayText']}}</span>
   </ng-container>
  </div>
  </option>
 </select>
</form>
```

and here is my component

```
PriceFilter = [
{
  "TagId": 20,
  "Type": "Budget",
  "Value": 5,
  "Values": null,
  "DisplayText": "$50",
  "Order": null
},
{
  "TagId": 20,
  "Type": "Budget",
  "Value": 15,
  "Values": null,
  "DisplayText": "$15",
  "Order": null
}]

Stores = [
{
  "Products": [
    {
    "ProductId": 206419,
    "Price": 39.99,
    "PriceLabel": "$39.99",
    "ProductTags": [1,2]
    },
    {
    "ProductId": 206419,
    "Price": 3.99,
    "PriceLabel": "$9.99",
    "ProductTags": [1,2]
    }
 ]}] // can add more fake data to it for testing

constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) { 
  this.myForm = this.fb.group({
    filterProduct: ['']
  })
}

ngOnInit() {
  this.myForm.get('filterProduct').valueChanges.subscribe(
    value => {
      this.Stores.forEach(x => {
        console.log(x.Products.filter(val => value.slice(1) >= 
  val['Price']))
      })
     //  this.Products.filter(val => value.slice(1) <= val['Price'])
    }
  )
}
```

Comment: It's not really clear what you're trying to achieve here. Is it that you need two select lists for Lower Limit and Upper Limit and then you want to filter the Products based on that?

Comment: No @SiddAjmera I want is only one drop down where first drop down should show   the first data of the list and other should follow first and between second like `(fist is $15 the other should show between first and second i.e. $15 and $50 and filter accordingly)` sorry for my bad english but hopefully you understand what I am trying to say

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For option value, you can set the `lower` and `upper` based on the `index` of the option. And then filter out, based on that.

The `getValue` method is meant to do just that. And this is the same object, that you'll receive as `value` for the `valueChanges` Observable. You can then do your filtering based on the `lower` and `upper`.

Try this:

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm">
    <select name="Price" formControlName="filterProduct">
    <option *ngFor="let k of PriceFilter; let i = index;"
      [ngValue]="getValue(i)">
      {{ getValue(i).displayText }}
    </option>
  </select>
</form>

<div>
  <ul>
    <li *ngFor= "let product of filteredProducts">
      {{ product | json }}
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

And in your Component Class:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  name = 'Angular';
  myForm: FormGroup;
  filteredProducts = [];
  PriceFilter = [{
      "TagId": 20,
      "Type": "Budget",
      "Value": 15,
      "Values": null,
      "DisplayText": "$15",
      "Order": null
    },
    {
      "TagId": 20,
      "Type": "Budget",
      "Value": 25,
      "Values": null,
      "DisplayText": "$25",
      "Order": null
    },
    {
      "TagId": 20,
      "Type": "Budget",
      "Value": 50,
      "Values": null,
      "DisplayText": "$50",
      "Order": null
    }
  ]

  Stores = [{
    "Products": [{
        "ProductId": 206419,
        "Price": 39.99,
        "PriceLabel": "$39.99",
        "ProductTags": [1, 2]
      },
      {
        "ProductId": 206419,
        "Price": 15.99,
        "PriceLabel": "$15.99",
        "ProductTags": [1, 2]
      },
      {
        "ProductId": 206419,
        "Price": 10.99,
        "PriceLabel": "$10.99",
        "ProductTags": [1, 2]
      },
      {
        "ProductId": 206419,
        "Price": 55.99,
        "PriceLabel": "$55.99",
        "ProductTags": [1, 2]
      },
      {
        "ProductId": 206419,
        "Price": 1.99,
        "PriceLabel": "$1.99",
        "ProductTags": [1, 2]
      },
      {
        "ProductId": 206419,
        "Price": 3.99,
        "PriceLabel": "$9.99",
        "ProductTags": [1, 2]
      }
    ]
  }]

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.myForm = this.fb.group({
      filterProduct: ['']
    })
  }

  getValue(index) {
    if (index === 0)
      return {
        lower: 0,
        displayText: this.PriceFilter[index].DisplayText,
        upper: this.PriceFilter[index].Value
      };
    else {
      return {
        lower: this.PriceFilter[index - 1].Value,
        upper: this.PriceFilter[index].Value,
        displayText: `${this.PriceFilter[index - 1].DisplayText} - ${this.PriceFilter[index].DisplayText}`
      };
    }
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.filteredProducts = [...this.Stores[0].Products];

    this.myForm.get('filterProduct').valueChanges.subscribe(
      value => {
        console.log(value);
        this.filteredProducts = [...this.Stores[0].Products.filter(product => product.Price >= value.lower && product.Price <= value.upper)]
      }
    )
  }
}
```

Here's a [**Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-product-filter?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) for your ref.

Comment: But sidd I also want to show this to the drop down not only single data of the list `i.e. $15-$50 should be in the drop down and filtered data should be accondily` BTW thanx yaar...

Answer (score 2):

I have modified your code a bit to accommodate logic for the use case you want. Also I am assuming this that your PriceFilter is configurable so that we can take advantage of it.

First of all you need to have `PriceFilter` modified to include `minValue` which you will need to compare store results.

Here is a working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ymdwpp?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Changes are as follows:

```
//PriceFilter object
  PriceFilter = [
    {
      "TagId": 20,
      "Type": "Budget",
      "maxValue": 15,
      "minValue": 0,
      "Values": null,
      "DisplayText": "$15",
      "Order": null
    }, {
      "TagId": 20,
      "Type": "Budget",
      "maxValue": 50,
      "minValue": 15,
      "Values": null,
      "DisplayText": "$15-$50",
      "Order": null
    }
  ]

//app.component.ts
  ngOnInit() {

  }

  onChange(index) {
    const filter = this.PriceFilter[index];
    this.Stores.forEach(x => {
      console.log(x.Products.filter(val => (filter.maxValue >= val['Price'] && filter.minValue < val['Price'])))
    })
  }

//app.component.html
<hello name="{{ name }}"></hello>
<p>
    open the console to see the result
</p>

<form [formGroup]="myForm">
    <select name="Price" formControlName="filterProduct" (change)="onChange($event.target.value)">
    <option *ngFor="let k of PriceFilter  | groupBy: 'maxValue' | keyvalue; let ind = index" [value]="ind">
      <div>
   <ng-container *ngFor= "let i of k['value']">
      <span>{{i['DisplayText']}}</span>
   </ng-container>
   </div>
    </option>
    </select>
</form>
<!-- Modify according to your need -->
```

Take a look and let me know if this helps.